# How print akka configuration at startup?

Tags: scala, configuration, akka, typesafe-config

I have a akka project with several config files. Is it possible to print akka merged configuration event when application starts (or stops) with errors?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [Configuration](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html):

> If the system or config property `akka.log-config-on-start` is set to
>   `on`, then the complete configuration at INFO level is logged when the actor
>   system is started.

Add the configuration in your config file to print the entire configuration as

```
akka {
  log-config-on-start = "on"
}
```